# How to make a GUI pushbutton open/close another GUI

Tags: matlab, user-interface, matlab-guide

I have a GUI called `GUI_main` in which I have a pushbutton called `pushbutton_GUI_main`. I currently have the following callback function implemented:

```
function pushbutton_GUI_main_Callback(hObject, eventdata, handles)

GUI_sub
```

Where `GUI_sub` is another GUI that opens when you click on `pushbutton_GUI_main`. However, I want something like the following:

```
function pushbutton_GUI_main_Callback(hObject, eventdata, handles)

if (GUI_sub == open)
   close(GUI_sub)
else
   GUI_sub
```

That is, with `pushbutton_GUI_main` I want to be able to open **and** close `GUI_sub`.

Comment: Does `GUI_sub` return a handle to itself? If so, you can probably store that handle in your GUI_main handles and then check its status. I haven't done that exact thing so I can't help with the exact implementation

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As *excaza* says, **handles** is a great way to pass data or information in a GUI.
Another way, if you for some reason don't want to store the GUI handle, perhaps if the GUI_sub could be created independently is to search for the figure handle.

```
subGuiH = findall(0,'Name','GUI_sub');
if ~isempty(subGuiH)
    close(subGuiH);
end
GUI_sub;
```

The search could be narrowed by adding

```
findall(0,'Type','figure','Name','GUI_sub')
```

Depending on your Matlab version, you could also checkout **groot**

Answer (score 2):

You need an object handle to reference the sub GUI. Assuming `GUI_sub` is a GUI built with GUIDE, it is programmed by default with an optional handle output.

A naive implementation for a GUIDE GUI would look something like this:

```
function pushbutton1_Callback(hObject, eventdata, handles)
if ~isempty(handles.figure1.UserData)
    close(handles.figure1.UserData);
    handles.figure1.UserData = [];
else
    handles.figure1.UserData = sub_GUI;
end
```

Most of (maybe all?) MATLAB's graphics objects have a `UserData` field by default. I've utilized the `UserData` of the base figure object for this simple example. See also: [Share Data Among Callbacks](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/creating_guis/share-data-among-callbacks.html) for other methods to store/transfer this data.